# Custom System.Runtime.Caching ChangeMonitor

Tags: .net, caching

Has anyone got any examples of creating a custom ChangeMonitor? I was hoping to implement a ChangeMonitor for Azure blob storage but there is very little documentation out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rolled my own solution for monitoring files in Azure storage. Full details [on my blog](http://ben.onfabrik.com/posts/monitoring-files-in-azure-blob-storage).

Answer (score 0):

The best (and really, only) article I've found on the subject is over here:  http://dotnetnate.com/2010/08/net-4-caching-runtime-custom-change-monitor/

The examples need a little cleaning up, but the core implementation is sound, and it gives a decent walk-through on all of the pieces necessary.

Comment: Sadly, the link returns 404.

Comment: Looks like the whole site is now returning 404.  Here's an archive.org version of the page (the pics don't show, but everything else does):  https://web.archive.org/web/20120815191400/http://dotnetnate.com/2010/08/net-4-caching-runtime-custom-change-monitor/